# Aligning columns in C output

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that displays the numerical value of certain characters constants (the ones in the `if` statements).  The code works, except for one problem. The output is supposed to be nicely aligned in columns, but as shown below, it isn't. What is the best way to get the columns to line up properly?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {

    unsigned char c;

    printf("%3s %9s %12s %12s\n", "Char", "Constant", "Description", "Value");

    for(c=0; c<= 127; ++c){

        if (c == '\n') {
            printf("%3d %7s \t%s \t\t%s%03x\n", c,"\\n","newline","0x", c);

        }else if (c == '\t'){
            printf("%3d %7s \t%s \t\t%s%03x\n", c,"\\t","horizontal tab","0x", c);

        }else if (c == '\v'){
            printf("%3d %7s \t%s \t\t%s%03x\n", c,"\\v","vertical tab","0x", c);

        }else if (c == '\b'){
            printf("%3d %7s \t%s \t\t%s%03x\n", c,"\\b","backspace","0x", c);

        }else if (c == '\r'){
            printf("%3d %7s \t%s \t\t%s%03x\n", c,"\\r","carriage return","0x", c);

        }else if (c == '\f'){
            printf("%3d %7s \t%s \t\t%s%03x\n", c,"\\f","form feed","0x", c);

        }else if (c == '\\'){
            printf("%3d %7s \t%s \t\t%s%03x\n", c,"\\","backslash","0x", c);

        }else if (c == '\''){
            printf("%3d %7s \t%s \t\t%s%03x\n", c,"\'","single quote","0x", c);

        }else if (c == '\"'){
            printf("%3d %7s \t%s \t\t%s%03x\n", c,"\"","double quote","0x", c);

        }else if (c == '\0'){
            printf("%3d %7s \t%s \t\t%s%03x\n", c,"\\0","null","0x", c);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

[image: Output]

Comment: A good solution here is the string justification/length option in format strings.  You're on the right track with tabs but because you have varying lengths in the description column it's throwing you off.  You may want to try `printf("%-30s", description) as a starting point.

Comment: If the code works then it's more suitable on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It doesn't work as the columns are supposed to be lined up but they are jagged

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `\t` leaves you at the mercy of your output device.  Instead you could use minimum field widths for the strings, e.g. `%-20s` will print at least 20 characters, right-padding with spaces.

`%-20.20s` will truncate the string if it was longer; `%-20s` will bump everything else over to the right. The `-` means to left-justify (default is right-justify)

---

To avoid code duplication you could use a helper function, e.g.:

```
void print_item(char code, char const *abbrev, char const *description)
{
     printf("%3d %7s %20.20s %#03x\n", code, abbrev, description, (unsigned char)code);
}

// ... in your function
if (c == '\n')
     print_item(c, "\\n", "newline");
```

I modified the printf format string:

- Using `%20.20s` as suggested above
- `%#03x`, the `#` means it will prepend `0x` for you
- `(unsigned char)code` for the last one means it will behave nicely if you passed any negative chars in. (Typically chars range in value from -128 to 127).

Comment: @EricWang it is like `%03x` but it will put `0x` at the start

Comment: I see, very nice answer.

Comment: @M.M can you please explain the difference between the first 20 and second 20?

Comment: @cokedude the first one means to print at least 20 characters, the second one means to print at most 20 characters. So the combined meaning is to print exactly 20