# Prevent Increasing Value from Pushing Another

Tags: c

Not sure how to phrase my question, sorry for the confusing title. Basically, I have two variables being displayed (score and high score) that increase as a user plays the game I am making.

```
    printf("Score: %d", score);
    printf("%s", SPACE);
    printf("High Score: %d", highScore);
```

When score increases as you play, it starts to push over high score beyond my "game board". I'm sure there's a basic fix for this, but I am new. How should I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aligning columns in C output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329208/aligning-columns-in-c-output)

Comment: Please make a [mre], along with the output you get and the output you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the length of a *string* using a [precision specifier in `printf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf). However, you're printing integers, for which `printf()` does not allow a "maximum length" specifier.

## `asprintf()`

To get around this, you could do the integer conversion *before* passing to printf() by using `asprintf()`:

```
char *score_str, *highScore_str;
asprintf(&score_str, "%d", score);
asprintf(&highScore_str, "%d", highScore);

printf("Score: %.5s", score_str);
printf("%s", SPACE);
printf("High Score: %.5s", highScore_str);

free(score_str);
free(highScore_str);
```

where `5` is the precision specifier—you can use any other positive number.
Note that `free()`ing the strings is very important: `asprintf()` dynamically allocates memory for those strings, and you (probably) don't want to leak memory on every print.

## `snprintf()`

Dynamically allocating memory here is unnecessary here, though, because we already know how long we want the strings to be. Using `snprintf()`, we can eliminate the need for `asprintf()` and the `printf()` precision specifier:

```
char score_str [6];
char highScore_str [6];

snprintf(score_str, 6, "%d", score);
snprintf(highScore_str, 6, "%d", highScore);

printf("Score: %s", score_str);
printf("%s", SPACE);
printf("High Score: %s", highScore_str);
```

Note that we use `6` in both the declarations and `snprintf()` to account for the terminating NUL.

---

Both code snippets produce identical output, such as this:

```
Score: 5 High Score: 12345
```

where `score = 5` and `highScore = 123456789`.

## `printf()` with a `double` argument

The above format has a problem: the scores are simply truncated (the remaining digits are deleted). This can be remedied with scientific notation. `e` and `E` are the `printf()` format specifiers for scientific notation, but `g` or `G` are probably preferred here, as they use simple decimal notation for small numbers.

```
printf("Score: %.5G", (double)score);
printf("%s", SPACE);
printf("High Score: %.5G", (double)highScore);
```

will produce output like

```
Score: 5 High Score: 1.2346E+08
```

With `.5` as the precision, we can guarantee that each number will not exceed 10 characters: 5 for the number score, 1 for the decimal, and 4 for the scientific notation.

Depending on the nature of your game, such a format may not be reasonable.

---

When confronted with the problem of fitting a number into a limited number of characters, there are always two options.

1. Truncate it, as we did in the first two examples.
2. Use a special notation, as we did in the third.

There's another way to look at option #2: use suffixes such as `k`, `M`, and `B` when the score gets too long. `printf()` does not provide such functionalityy, so you would have to implement that system (which I assume is the most desirable) yourself.