# How does ls, exa, lsd compute columns and rows when printing filenames?

Tags: algorithm, logic

what's should be the logic behind `ls`, [exa](https://github.com/ogham/exa), [lsd](https://github.com/Peltoche/lsd) command when computing how many rows and columns is needed depending on the terminal width.

what I currently know is by using `terminal_width / max_length_of_filenames` which is a step behind of what I want to achive.

I've also tried to look inside the coreutils ls codebase but I'm not understanding much of it.

Comment: It's not really programming language specific. You'd use the same logic no matter what language it's written in.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, it's not really PL-specific. Can you elaborate on what is the logic in implementing this?

Comment: You can probably work out the logic yourself. `ls` bases the width of each columns on its longest item and it tries to maximize column numbers. It leaves a gutter of two spaces between columns. You can guess the minimum number of columns from the longest file name and then "probe" successivly tighter designs until the names won't fit. Then use the last valid design to print the names.

Comment: That sounds straightforward, but there are some pitfalls. When the number of files isn't evenly divisible by the number of columns, you get an incomplete last line, which you must cater for. The items are printed column-wise, which helps finding the individual column widths, but makes the essentially row-wise process of printing more complex.

Comment: I do not know how `ls` does it, but an algorithm is: Read, remember, and sort all the file names. Let N be the number of them. Examine all the file name lengths to find the maximum, L. Let W be the window width and G be the gutter size (number of blank spaces between columns, for readability). Then C = floor((W+G)/(L+G)) columns will fit in the window and allow space for each file name in any column. Next, set indices for which name to print in which column: I0 = 0, I1 = ceil(N/C), I2 = I1+ceil((N-I1)/(C-1), I3 = ceil((N-I2)/(C-2),… Print a row of file names at the calculated indices,…

Comment: … increment the indices, and repeat, but suppressing the printing of a file name when the index for its column reaches the starting index of the next column (or, for the last column, reaches N).

Comment: An alternate calculation for the starting indices is to set all of them to floor(N/C) and then increment each of the first N%C indices.

Answer (score 1):

TlDR; `ls` uses a fairly complex process. If you just want to print your data in nice columns, there are [easier solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35329877/15381660) for that.

So, how does GNU's ls do it?

It first calculates the maximum amount of possible columns. That is simply the line length of the terminal divided by 3; 1 character and 2 spaces to separate, with an adjustment for one without spaces. If the total number of files is greater than that, the maximum number of columns is set to that instead.

```
max_idx = line_length / MIN_COLUMN_WIDTH - 1
max_cols = max_idx < total_files ? max_idx : total_files
```

It then allocates an array of that many `column_info` structures. Perhaps counterintuitively, these structures do not actually represent columns, but different possible column configurations. The eventual number of columns is used as an index in this array to select the correct one. For the purpose of explanation, I will refer to them as configurations.

These structures have a flag `valid` to indicate if this configuration can be used, a field `line_len` which is the length of the line if using this configuration, and an array of column widths called `col_arr`. This array is larger for every consecutive possible configuration; a configuration with only 1 column needs only one element.

You can mentally visualize it like this

```
0 | x
1 | x x
2 | x x x
```

where the first column represents the total number of columns, and each 'x' represents a column for that configuration.

It loops over the files, and for each file it loops over each possible column configuration. It checks if the configuration is still valid, and if it is not it simply skips it.

It then calculates in what column this file would be using the current configuration. How it does that depends on its mode.
When it prints horizontally, the column is the remainder of dividing the file index by the number of columns.

```
idx = filesno % (i+1)
```

When it prints vertically (the default), it is the file index divided by the maximized files per column:

```
idx = filesno / ((total_files + i) / (i + 1))
```

where i = the configuration index, and idx = the column.

Then it checks the width for this column in this configuration against the width of the filename. If the filename is longer, it changes the configuration's column width and add to its line length. It checks if this configuration would then exceed the screen width. If so, it marks the configuration as invalid.

Finally, it scans from the back to find the highest valid configuration and that is the resulting number of columns.

When printing it has to jump back and forth through the file array, because printing always happens horizontally. It calculates the number of rows by dividing the number of files by the number of columns (with an optional extra one if there is a remainder). Then for every row it loops over the files in steps equal to the number of columns.

Lets take this example output:

```
a c e
b d
```

Assuming that the maximum number of columns of the terminal would be 4 (otherwise it would just print one line).

It starts with file 'a' (filesno=0). Dividing zero by anything will be zero, so for every configuration this sets column 0.
Then it moves on to file 'b' (filesno=1). As long as the second part of the expression > 1, idx will be 0. That stops when it reaches configuration 4. Being zero indexed, so with 5 colums, 'b' would be printed next to 'a'. If we input that in the above expression, we get `1 / ((5+4)/(4+1)) == 1 / 1 == 1`, so it would end up in column 1. It adds to the length of configuration 4.

However, 'c' with configuration 4 will set column 2, so add more to the length of it. And once it reaches 'd', for configuration 4, it will set column 3. But by then the length of configuration would fall off the screen, so it is marked as invalid.

When it's done, it loops backward from 5, and finds that 3 is the last valid configuration, so it prints 3 columns.

Comment: I was writing a blog post, where I recreated Linux `ls` command, with different flags. When I reached tabular printing part, I stumbled just right here. Thanks to your awesome explanation, I was able to implement it. For anyone who is interested coding implementation of this answer: https://mmzeynalli.dev/posts/reinvent/ls/part5/#3-tabular